# How to add additional data to an AJAX file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, flask

I am uploading an image file to a Flask endpoint using AJAX.  I want to send metadata (author, publication date, etc) alongside the file in the same AJAX upload.

My JQuery code looks like:

```
    $("#upload_btn").click(function() { 
        var fd = new FormData(); 
        var file = $('#file_input')[0].files[0]; 
        // Build AJAX request
        fd.append('file', file);               // This works fine, the file is uploaded
        fd.append('author', 'Test Auth');      // I'd expect this to upload but it doesn't
        fd.append('pub_date', '01 Jan 2018');  // nor this
        $.ajax({ 
            url: '{{ upload_url }}', 
            type: 'post', 
            data: fd, 
            contentType: false, 
            processData: false, 
            xhr: function () {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) {
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                        $('#progress').text(percentComplete + '%');
                        $('#progress').css('width', percentComplete + '%');
                    }
                }, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("load", function(evt){ 
                    var results = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                    if(results.result == 'ok'){ 
                        $('#progress_status').text('SUCCESS: Upload complete');
                    } 
                    else{ 
                        $('#progress_status').text('APP ERROR: ' + results.message);
                    } 
                }, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("error", function(jqXHR, textStatus, exception){ 
                    $('#progress_status').text('SYSTEM ERROR');
                }, false);
                return xhr;
            },
        }); 
    });
```

At the Flask endpoint I would have expected to be able to retrieve author using:

```
    print(request.data['author'])
```

or possibly:

```
    print(request.data.author)
```

but neither work.

My Flask endpoint code looks like:

```
@targets.route("/upload_file", methods=["POST"])
def upload_file():
    print("AA: Entered upload_file function")
    print(request.data['author'])
    file = request.files["file"]
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file_handle = save_user_file(file)
    if file_handle is None:
        results = {"result": "error",
                   "message": "Could not save file",
                   "file_handle": None}
    else:
        results = {"result": "ok",
                   "message": "File uploaded",
                   "file_handle": file_handle}
    return jsonify(results)
```

The print(request.data['author']) statement raises the error:

```
TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Obviously data is a blob and I'm not accessing the correct element of the request object.

What approach should I be using to send metadata alongside the uploaded file and retrieve it at the endpoint?

Comment: The JS is correct. I can only assume the issue lies with how you're accessing the request body through Flask

Comment: Added the current endpoint code. If the JS is correct then it must be that I'm not understanding how to retrieve the data from the request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form data comes attached to the request as `request.form`, `request.data` is always a string AFAIK. So just try `author = request.form["author"]` or something like that.

Comment: That was it. Obvious really! Many thanks.

Comment: np, happy coding!