# Javascript FormData, is it possible to append 'key val' to a file?

Tags: javascript, form-data

Im sending a form with multiple files using formData, and i would like to add a 'flag' to one of this files.

Im trying something like this without success:

```
for (let file of fu.files) {
 if (file.name == 'x') file.flag = true;
 else file.flag = false;
 formData.append(name, file, file.name);
}
```

And the file in the request starts with:

```
-----------------------------22161056743320652140255036212
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_0"; filename="name.jpeg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
... image ...
```

Exactly what i want is to add a custom key val like 'name' or 'filename', an receive it easily on the server side.

I can resolve it by other means, like adding another field to formData, but im wondering if is it possible in the way im asking.

Comment: This might be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59142307/how-to-add-additional-data-to-an-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Thanks Olivier, but that would be like adding just another field to formData.

Comment: That's not possible, for sure.